# Has React killed the concept of Shadow-DOM

Tags: reactjs, shadow-dom

Shadow DOM is designed as a tool for building component-based apps.

But if I use component based styling in React, which means that each component loads only it's own CSS file, do I still need the concept of Shadow DOM?

Comment: They a 2 concurrent concepts.

Comment: Does it mean that inside of a React app, if I use the concept of component based styling, I don't need to use the classic shadow-DOM using shadowRoot. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement "Shadow DOM is designed as a tool for building component-based apps." is inaccurate and should be "Shadow DOM is designed to encapsulate DOM and CSS." *I can use Shadow DOM without writing a single component and I can write a component without Shadow DOM.*

React is one of many frameworks that do their own thing for their own type of components. But that does not remove the purpose of Shadow DOM.

Standard HTML elements uses Shadow DOM. Elements like `<video>` and `<audio>` are great examples. You don't see what is inside the Shadow DOM and you don't need to.

If more component developers would use `<audio>` and `<video>` as examples of how to write small, re-usable components then things would fit together better. But, all to often, developers want to make their entire page into a single component and that is not the best way to write code.

React, Vue, Angular and others have their way of creating components and pages. Whether they use Shadow DOM or not is irrelevant to the need and use of Shadow DOM.